# Trying to make an algorithm which results in the image attached to that topic

Tags: algorithm, math, glsl, shader

I'm actually trying to make an algorithm that looks like cubic bézier, but i was wondering if there was an easier solution.
Here is what i want :

[image]

- This graph is length 1 and height 1.
- The red line is the actual input i have.
- The yellow dot is a given argument we can call "warp", between 0 and 1.
- The green line is what i want as a result.

There should be another argument that we can call "warp_pow", which represents the amount of interpolation.
I'm actually doing it for a GLSL shader, but if it's not a GLSL code it's not a big deal, it will help me a lot anyways :)

Comment: Re "i was wondering if there was an easier solution": Please define / clarify "easier". Easier in what way? Re "`warp_pow`, which represents the amount of interpolation": Please clarify what this means. I guess this means how big the bulge (deviation from straight diagonal line) is, with a warp_pow of 1 representing a straight line?

Comment: When i'm talking about "an easier solution" i mean that cubic bézier is a pretty complex algorithm, and i don't need 100% if that. In my case, my interpolation is always the same (horizontal). And for warp_pow, you're right, and a value of 1 can't be a straight line, because it's important for my use to always have that sort of curve snapping, where x=0 have always y=0, and same for 1.

Comment: By easier, do you mean requiring a smaller number of basic math operations than are needed to evaluate a cubic spline (with FMA available, it seems to take about 10 operations)? What is the significance of the shaping parameter `warp_pow` being (according to the name) a power, instead of a simple scale factor?

Comment: Well, if you want a horizontal tangent at the yellow dot, maybe `a + (x - a)^3` works, where `(a, a)` is the location of the dot. You might need some other terms to ensure you hit (0, 0) and (1, 1).

Comment: I made this algorithm but is not totally what i wanted :
`vec2 cage = (1. -pow(abs(sin( gl_FragCoord.xy / u_resolution * PI - PI / 2. )), vec2(5.))) ;
vec2 st = lerp(gl_FragCoord.xy, u_mouse, cage * POWER * force) / u_resolution;` 
It works, but doesn't really have that property of "snapping to the edges" properly like bézier curves.